# Problems with Rails on Namecheap server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment

O. Community, and thanks in advance for the support!

I recently took Mattan Griffel's One Month Rails course on skillshare to be able to write rails web apps.
Railsinstaller.org includes rails 3.2.1 and ruby 1.9.3 and works perfectly out of the box.
My app worked well and it was time to get it up on the web, so I purchased a namecheap domain and webserver, uploaded my app and... nothing!
The problem is that the namecheap servers only support rails 2.3.17 and ruby 1.8.7 - nothing created with v 3.x or dependent on ruby 1.9.x will run in a 2.x / 1.8.x environment.
Has anyone else run into this issue? 
It seems like such a standard use case, I can't believe it's not better documented on the namecheap site.
I've done my Google-Fu and have learned that, once I installed it, I could create an older rails app using

```
rails _2.3.17_ AppName
```

Is there a similar way of forcing rails to use an older version of ruby as well?
I'm close to cancelling my namecheap account altogether in disgust, so if someone out there knows of a better place to host my rails 3.x web apps, I'd love to hear about it!
(Let's assume, for the time being, that a VPS is prohibitively expensive and far in excess of what I need, resource-wise).

Thanks again,
One Frustrated User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use heroku free account to begin with. Don't waste time on fixing problems on shared hostings, they are just toys.

Comment: Thanks Billy.
Indeed, I was able to deploy to heroku without problem as part of the coursework, and perhaps this was the way I should have gone.

Comment: Yes, you should go that way. Shared hosting are designed for simple html and php script. For Rails you need Heroku, Amazon AWS, Rackspace, Linode or other VPS.

Comment: Definitely. I'm cancelling my namecheap account today. Thanks so much to everyone who replied!

Answer (score 2):

Rails 3.x native cPanel support is still unreleased , feature request case is still open
http://forums.cpanel.net/f145/mod_rails-passenger-instead-mongrel-rails-3-support-case-44197-a-152577.html

This is tricky but possible to run Ruby 3 applications - additional software installation and global server reconfiguration required in this case, but hardly possible on regular shared server per user. We can offer to upgrade your hosting account to VPS. All your existing account content including databases, additional domains, email accounts and settings will be transferred transparently to VPS. To optimize your VPS with cPanel and make possible for you to develop and run Ruby 3 application you may request our technical support team to tune up the system according to all your requirements. Operating system tuning and custom software installation is included with Full Management VPS option. You may request part-time technical support as an alternative.

Regards,

### Dima S.

Technical Support,
Namecheap Hosting

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, Dima. If I haven't said it before in your tech support forums, the attentiveness of your customer service department is just fantastic. However...

Comment: At a certain point you're going to start loosing business if the product doesn't perform as advertised. I'd like to point out the ticket to which you referred me was first opened around this time **three years ago**. It's therefore more than a little dishonest to claim ROR support given that you cannot handle applications built using the beginner-friendly Rails 3.x and Ruby 1.9.x.
Last week I filed a ticket at your support site entitled "Namecheap RoR Support is a LIE used to upsell their VPS - Don't be fooled!" (eventually I'll get around to posting it openly to S.O.)...

Comment: The title pretty much says it all - you're luring in customers with the promise of ROR support and attractive pricing, then once they're all paid up and properly _baited_, you pull the _switch_ on them; namely, that they need to now purchase your VPS package as well in order to actually make use of the service they wanted in the first place...

Comment: It's impressive how "on script" every namecheap technician is on this point and I bet your conversion rate (as a company) is correspondingly impressive. Given how this issue is 3 years old, you really need to include a warning/footnote on your site. Take a look at [your published tech specs page](https://www.namecheap.com/web-hosting/web-hosting/tech-specs.aspx). Under SERVER FEATURES, the ULTIMATE package clearly asserts ROR and the corresponding info tab, - instead of informing us about the severe limitations of the service - instead describes the ROR framework.

Comment: If your company were not deliberately trying to fool potential customers into purchasing a service incompatible with the product they had designed, you would specify ROR 2.3.17 with Ruby 1.8.7 in the ROR row heading analogous to the that of Apache (2.x) PHP (5.x.x.) or MySQL (5.x.x), just a few rows up and within the same category.
I will be in touch with your company today to cancel my namecheap shared server account and will be seeking a full refund. For anyone following this thread, I'll be posting your response here, alongside the comical transcripts of all your attempts to upsell VPS.